Why is my C# code not updating the database record and row not select properly?
I am working on a C# application on adding admin to the database. I can select a data row from a grid, and the details of the selected row are displayed in textboxes for editing. However, when I change the textboxes and click the "Update" button, I get this error:

Select a record to update

even though I have already selected a row and the details are displayed correctly in the form. My SQL Server works properly.
This is a code of my updating and row selection:
private void adminview_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.RowIndex != -1 && e.ColumnIndex != -1) 
    { 
        mobile = Convert.ToInt32(adminview.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value);
    } 
    else 
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid cell selected."); 
    }

    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = adminview.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        aname.Text = row.Cells["username"].Value.ToString();
        amobile.Text = row.Cells["mobile"].Value.ToString();
        adate.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["birth"].Value);   
        pw.Text = row.Cells["password"].Value.ToString();

        if (row.Cells["gender"].Value.ToString() == "Male")
        {
            amale.Checked = true;
            afemale.Checked = false;
        }
        else if (row.Cells["gender"].Value.ToString() == "Female")
        {
            afemale.Checked = true;
            amale.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}

private void update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (adminview.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
        name = aname.Text;
        mobile = Convert.ToInt32(amobile.Text);
        dob = adate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        passw = pw.Text;

        if (amale.Checked == true)
        {
            gender = "Male";
        }
        else if (afemale.Checked == true)
        {
            gender = "Female";
        }

        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE admin SET name = '" + name + "', password = '" + passw + "', gender = '" + gender + "', birth = '" + dob + "' WHERE mobile = '" + mobile + "'", conn);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Details updated");
        conn.Close();

        Display(); //data show in grid
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Select a record to update.");
    }
}

I expect to update my data in the database and row select in the grid correctly.

Apparently, there are 0 SelectedRows in your adminview. Can you think of a reason why?

Please use parameters instead of building values into a command string. Look up 'sql injection'

If you know the type of your data in a DataGridView then cast your result, don't convert it. Use (DateTime)row.Cells["birth"].Value instead of Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["birth"].Value) and (string)row.Cells["username"].Value instead of row.Cells["username"].Value.ToString().

after putting your code in a more readable format, can you spot one or more errors ?

Unrelated: do not persist passwords, not even "just for learning". It is never ok. If you don't really care, don't have any. If you do, learn how to do it right from the start.

Try it this way. Row selection can be done with this code.
 private void adminview_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)  
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = adminview.Rows[e.RowIndex];

         
        string mobileStr = row.Cells["mobile"].Value.ToString();
        if (int.TryParse(mobileStr.TrimStart('0'), out mobile))  
        {
            aname.Text = row.Cells["username"].Value.ToString();
            amobile.Text = mobileStr;  
            adate.Value = (DateTime)row.Cells["birth"].Value; 
            pw.Text = row.Cells["password"].Value.ToString();

            if (row.Cells["gender"].Value.ToString() == "Male")
            {
                amale.Checked = true;
                afemale.Checked = false;
            }
            else
            {
                afemale.Checked = true;
                amale.Checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid cell selected.");
    }
}


The issue is likely due to incorrectly checking for a selected row. Replace adminview.SelectedRows.Count > 0 with adminview.CurrentCell != null in your update_Click method. This will ensure you're only trying to update when a single row is selected

Could you please expound your answer?

The issue is likely due to incorrectly checking for a selected row. Replace adminview.SelectedRows.Count > 0 with adminview.CurrentCell != null in your update_Click method. This will ensure you're only trying to update when a single row is selected.

Please put that in your answer. Comments should be treated as ephemeral.

Try it this way. Update will work.
private void update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (adminview.CurrentCell != null && mobile != 0)
    {
        name = aname.Text;
        mobile = Convert.ToInt32(amobile.Text.TrimStart('0')); 
        dob = adate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        passw = pw.Text;

        if (amale.Checked)
        {
            gender = "Male";
        }
        else if (afemale.Checked)
        {
            gender = "Female";
        }

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE admin SET username = @username, password = @password, gender = @gender, birth = @birth WHERE mobile = @mobile", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passw);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gender);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birth", dob);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", mobile);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            Display();
            MessageBox.Show("Details Updated.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error updating record: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Select a record to update.");
        conn.Close();
    }
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
